# android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Binder.java)

Tags: android, crash

I will say at once the problem is not related to intent. The problem occurs on android 8-9. Model of phones samsung and motorola.I would appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash? At what moment does it occur?

Comment: @art can't reproduce

Comment: despite that you say that the problem is not related to `Intent` I notice that I had the same exception and the reason was that too large amount of data was passed in `Intent`'s extras. Are you sure you don't have something similar?